# Can not change Column names (fields) in Community Builder "record list" component

Tags: community, community-builder

can you tell me how i can change the colums like "Name", "Company" or "Stae Province"   into ohter fields from Lead object? eg show custom fields instead of these fields mentioned and seen in picture (Lead ListView)?

[image]

Is it even possible?
Hope anybody can help me out.
Thank you.

Best regards
Werner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can create a List View for the Lead object (e.g. "All - Custom" in my screenshot), with the desired fields/columns arrangement. Go to Leads tab, then click "Create New View" link next to the List Views dropdown.
[image: Lead List View Customization]

Once the List View is created, in the Community Builder go to Page Editor of the page where you would like to modify the Record List, click on the Record List component within the page, and then select your newly created List View from the Filter Name dropdown (the last dropdown in my screenshot).

[image: Record List Filter Cusstomization]